# Using Python Scrapy to Scrape Coupon Website

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the coupon codes from this website: https://www.cuponation.com.sg/zalora-coupon

I just want the codes (that are usually displayed after user clicks "view code", and the coupon code will open up in a new tab while the original tab will re-direct to the merchant's website) Take note that I only want the codes, and therefore do not want to click on the buttons which are "view discounts".

I've attached some summary code, and have also tried to view the network requests after clicking "view code" so that I can get python to send the correct network requests to scrape the coupon code, but seems to be unable to do so. The only alternative seems to be using Selenium to simulate a user click, but this is too tedious and resource-heavy. Instead, is there a way for Python to fire the right network request and output the codes all to a json file for viewing.

Tried adapting summary code below, but cannot seem to identify the right network requests being fired to obtain the coupon code.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class VoucherItem(Item):
    voucher_id = Field()
    code = Field()


class CuponationSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "cuponation"
    allowed_domains = ["cuponation.in"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.cuponation.in/babyoye-coupons"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        crawled_items = hxs.select('//div[@class="six columns voucher-btn"]/a')
        for button in crawled_items:
            voucher_id = button.select('@data-voucher-id').extract()[0]

            item = VoucherItem()
            item['voucher_id'] = voucher_id
            request = Request("https://www.cuponation.in/clickout/index/id/%s" % voucher_id,
                              callback=self.parse_code,
                              meta={'item': item})
            yield request

    def parse_code(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['code'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="code-field"]/span/text()').extract()

        return item
```

Expected Output:

```
{"voucher_id": "5735", "code": ["MUM10"]}
{"voucher_id": "5446", "code": ["APP20"]}
{"voucher_id": "3963", "code": ["CNATION150"]}
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to scrape just one page as a Proof of Concept or POC first. 

Also, asking for help with a spider where you cannot pinpoint the problem discourages people from putting their minds together and writing a solution for you.

So, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @AnuvratParashar it is in getting the right network requests for python to fire to retrieve the coupon code

Comment: Try to do it with plain old requests + lxml first.
Scrapy can help you manage and run scrapers at scale, but going back to the basics helps solve these pesky issues.